# Forcing ALSA to use another codec

Tags: 12.10, alsa, realtek, codecs

ALSA detects my sound card to be a `Realtek ALC1200` , but it is a `Realtek ALC888S`. This causes the sound to be lesser that that in my Windows XP Installation.

So, is it possible to make ALSA use the `Realtek ALC888S` codec instead of the `Realtek ALC1200` codec?

Comment: The ALC1200 is an ALC888 variant. Why do you think that your sound problem, whatever it is, is related with the chip's marketing name?

Comment: This causes the sound to be lesser in volume that that in my Windows XP Installation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1426424

> gksudo gedit Then open /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
>
> At the end of the file add a new line options snd-hda-intel
>
> model=generic

Comment: Tried that. Not working :(